# How to compute rpart complexity parameter?

Tags: r, binary-tree, regression, rpart

How is the `rpart` complexity parameter (cp) calculated?

For example I fit this model:

```
library(mlbench)
library(rpart)

data("Ozone")
Ozone <- na.omit(Ozone)

tree <- rpart(V4~.,data=Ozone,minsplit=2,cp=0,maxdepth=2)
summary(tree)
```

I get this as a result of `summary(tree)` and would like to know how the highlighted values are calculated:

[image: summary tree]

Answer (score 1):

For regression, the cp equals the decrease of "rel error".
for example, the cp of Node Number 1, 0.5882099 = 1 - 0.4117901

Comment: How can i calculate the real error?  and i dont really understand the way you calculate the CP if it's the decrease in the real error, how you calculate it  for node nnumber 2 ?